# Excel scenario - how to increment value

Tags: excel

With excel what if when creating a scenario it asks if you would like to change the value too. I'd like to put function in here like change the value to what it was before plus 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scenario Manager only works with fixed values. Notice that you cannot click in a cell. If you enter a formula for a value Excel will convert it to a fixed value.

It would be possible to do this with VBA, as the code could work out the results of formulas before assigning them as Scenario values.

Comment: so write a code to make or edit the scenario with correct value? I amk not familiar with vba so ill have to research that... thx!

Comment: Record a few macros and explore the code that it creates. Good luck.